# PHP $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] escaping, does this look acceptable?

Tags: php, escaping

I am just learning about escaping things and started reading about how it could be risky to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` due to XSS attacks.

I came up with this and was wondering if I could get some feedback on my attempt.

```
htmlspecialchars(
    filter_var( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL ),
    ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'
)
```

Does it look okay?

So much depends on this one variable being secure, I just had to ask for input.

**EDIT:**

I will be using this for display throughout the site, including basic anchor-hrefs, form-actions, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different escaping functions should be used for different situations, for example:

- [`urlencode`](https://www.php.net/http-build-query) for items that will be dropped in a query string in an `<a>` tag, ie. `echo '<a href="index.php?foo=' . urlencode($foo) . '">';` (see also [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/http-build-query))
- [`mysql_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/mysql-real-escape-string) for variables going in a SQL statement (though I prefer bind variable)
- [`htmlentities`](https://www.php.net/htmlentities) for strings you want to display to the user, that may possibly have HTML within (see also [`strip_tags`](https://www.php.net/strip-tags))

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what do you want to use for. If you want to display it, use htmlspecialchars. If you want to use as a database query, you might use mysql_real_escape_string in case of mysql. (or prepared statements)